# Почему на странице регистрации 5 вариантов, а в модальном окне 3?

Tags: дефект, поддержка, регистрация

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/signup

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В модальном окне при попытке оставить комментарий незарегистрированным пользователем:

> [image: ...]

Comment: Вангую, ВК и Яндекс — расширения руСО, а отзывы — стандартная тема для всех сайтов.